# in velocity can you iterate through a java hashmap's entry set()?

Tags: java, xml, velocity, template-engine

Can you do something like this in a velocity template?

```
#set ($map = $myobject.getMap() )
#foreach ($mapEntry in $map.entrySet())
    <name>$mapEntry.key()</name>
    <value>$mapEntry.value()</value>
#end
```

it outputs blank tags like so:

```
<name></name>
```

and

```
<value></value>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: it outputs blank tags <name></name>  and <value></value>

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Your mistake is referring to *key* and *value* as methods (with trailing "()" parenthesis) instead of as properties. Try this:

```
#set ($map = $myobject.getMap() )
#foreach ($mapEntry in $map.entrySet())
    <name>$mapEntry.key</name>
    <value>$mapEntry.value</value>
#end
```

In other words, use either a property, like *mapEntry.key*, or the method, like *mapEntry.getKey()*.

Answer (score 6):

I'm looking for a way to loop through a HashMap in velocity, and this will work too.

```
#set ($map = $myobject.getMap())
#foreach( $key in $map.keySet())
      <name>$key</name>
      <value>$resume.get($key)</value>
#end
```

Just like the way you would loop through a HashMap in java.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify (I cannot comment), in general you can use either the Java get  methods, or replace them by the corresponding name without with a small letter and without `()`.

So `$mapEntry.getKey()` or `map.key`.

Answer (score 1):

Here the Value

```
itemsValue={data1=1,data2=2,data3=3}
```

So , we need to iterate the group of value;

```
foreach ($key in ${itemsValue.keySet()})
   if($itemsValue.get($key)==1)
        Condition
   end
end
```

In the above code we can see check the value will be like -"data1,data2 etc ..."
but after using the get(), we can able to get the instance value.