# Velocity table from Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, foreach, velocity

I want to create a table within a Velocity template which gets it data from a `Map<String, List<String>>`. I tried it with nested `foreach` loops, but for some reason it didn't work (empty table even if data is present).

Adding the data to my model

```
model.put("downloaded", holder.getDownloadedFiles());
```

this adds a map as described above.

my template:

```
<table >
<tr>
    <th style="width:150px">Subsystem</th>
    <th style="width:500px">Filename</th>
</tr>

#foreach( $system in $downloaded.keySet)
#foreach($file in ${downloaded.get($system)})
    <tr>
    #if($foreach.count == 1) ##do only once
        <td rowspan=$downloaded.get($system).size()>$system</td>
    #end
        <td>$file</td>
    </tr>

#end
#end
</table>
```

For now I would be happy, to have a table like this (key should be 1 cell over multiple columns):

```
key    value1
       value2
       value3
       value4
key2   value1
       value2
       value3
       value4
```

**Do I access variables right and call methods properly?**

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: @MauricePerry empty table, but my map is filled

Comment: You defined "uploaded" and referenced "downloaded"

Comment: was a typo. edited it

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Are you getting an error? Do you see something different than you wanted to?

Comment: @TamasRev no error, but my table is empty even to i provide it with values

Comment: Should the first foreach not be: #foreach( $system in $downloaded.keySet()) - i.e. keySet(), not keySet

Comment: @JamesB that seemed to be it. i tried with that earlier but didn't get any result and wasn't sure about how to call methods properly. anyways, thanks. create an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Better solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2050260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
#foreach( $system in $downloaded.keySet)
```

for the outer loop you should use

```
#foreach( $system in $downloaded.keySet())
```